# How the R.java file generate unique id for resources

Tags: android

Where can I got it got to implement in my project to generate unique IDs in the same ways.

Comment: Um, what do you mean? You need unique ids? Use the Uuid class.

Answer (score 0):

When your project is build the R.java class is generated and it gives unique ID to every resource.
You shouldn't edit that class. If Eclipse doesn't create R.java file for your project try cleaning it by going to **Project > Clean**

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I mean I have to impliment the same logic to generate unique ids in my project for different component created at runtime.